# Selenium Webdriver: Checking all fonts on a page

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

For a Sprint-story, I need to assert that a certain font is not available anymore on different pages. Right now, I can verify that a certain element doesn't contain a font and is indeed replaced by another, but is there a way to check entire pages for the presence of a certain font?

I use Selenium Webdriver cucumber/Java within IntelliJ.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the font is specified through a `FONT` tag or CSS. `FONT` tags are obsolete now and discouraged from use but you could use the code below to find them and write the entire tag out to the console.

```
    // find FONT tags
    List<WebElement> foundFontTags = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("font[face*='fontname']"));
    for (WebElement foundFontTag : foundFontTags)
    {
        System.out.println(foundFontTag.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
    }
```

To find it in the CSS is going to be a bit more tricky. Your best bet is to talk to dev or your design team and ask how the font might be specified (if you don't already know). The problem is that without that knowledge, you are going to be looking all over the place for the font. It could be specified inline, a `STYLE` block, in a separate `.css` file, and so on each of which is going to require its own search. I provided one example for searching for a font in an inline CSS style.

```
    // find font-face in inline CSS
    foundFontTags = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[style*='font-family:fontname']"));
    for (WebElement foundFontTag : foundFontTags)
    {
        System.out.println(foundFontTag.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
    }
```

If the font is not specified in an external .css file, you might be able to get away with a text search of the entire HTML source for "font-face:fontname".

One other caveat... just because you find a definition of a css class that contains the wrong font doesn't mean it's actually applied to a visible element. That's a whole other issue. You probably should get a good definition of what success looks like from the Sprint team.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Selenium like so:

```
WebElement.getCssValue("text-align")
```

But this will be a bit tricky for all the CSS you'll have to validate. Here is a [good article](http://www.drobsonconsulting.co.uk/checking-css-styles-using-selenium-webdriver/) about that . Maybe a CSS unit testing like [Quixote](https://github.com/jamesshore/quixote) libs/frameworks will be a better fit. Other possible way (that I've used succesfuly) - visual regressions with  [huxley](https://github.com/facebookarchive/huxley), it can support your entire layout presentation's validation.